# HTML and CSS different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following HTML

```
<tr>
<td align="left">
<span wicket:id="valuenotifier">
<label name="currentValue" id="currentValue" wicket:id="currentValue" />%
</span> 
</td>
</tr>
```

and CSS

```
#currentValue {
font-size: 45px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: normal;
line-height:inherit;      
}
```

What's driving me nuts is that they layout in slightly different way between Firefox and Chrome. In Chrome they are where I put them. In Firefox, the table pushed the table above and below up and down (respectively) by a few pixels. Driving me nuts. Anyone got an idea how to stop it? (Can't tell you about IE for reasons I won't bore you with.)

Comment: Reset the CSS, something like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).  Browsers have different base CSS, so overwrite the base, and write all your own.  Your CSS will not change from browser to browser.

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ "Makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing."

Comment: Thanks - that didn't work when I dumped the whole thing in there. I might have to go through the elements one by one till I find the right one

Answer (score 2):

do

```
-moz-margin:0px; 
-webkit-margin:0px;
```

in your Css